# What is meaning of 'cold wind blowing visit'?

Tags: meaning-in-context, idioms

The following sentence can be found on [this Quora page](https://www.quora.com/What-was-the-geopolitical-interest-the-main-reason-of-USSR-supporting-India-in-1971-Indo-Pak-war#!n=12):

> Indian Prime Minister Indira Gandhi visited the US in November - weeks before the war with Pakistan and that visit was a cold wind blowing.

What is meaning of 'cold wind blowing visit'?

Comment: As for why I made my edit, you should read [**this**](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1084/so-you-found-a-sentence-or-phrase-why-you-should-cite-your-source).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't say "cold wind blowing visit" - "a cold wind blowing" is a noun phrase, the complement of "was".

With an adjectival modifier, we can move it to complement position, so

> The green door ...

implies that we can say

> The door is green.

But, while a noun phrase *can* sometimes be used to modify a noun phrase, we can't normally use the same noun phrase as complement; or if we can, it won't have the same meaning. So:

> The village green ...

but not

> *The green is village. (or *The green is a village)

And conversely

> The man is a builder

but not normally

> *The builder man ...

"A cold wind blowing" is a metaphor for something unwelcome, or something which suggests that something unwelcome will follow.

Comment: The village green can be village parks,forests,etc,right?

Comment: No, "village green" means a grass-covered open space within the village.  [See definition #4 of the noun "green".](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/green)